# Add custom listview to a fragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to work with a custom listview in a fragment, and I tried a lot of things, I watched videos and I looked for solutions in this site, but I get confused because it doesn't work.
My problem is that in the code, I can't make work the custom adapter, it crash when the fragment inflates, and with the "(AppCompatActivity)" added, it doesn't crash but the listview doesn't show anything.

Is there something I could do with this?
Should I try another thing?

This is the Fragment I want to use the ListView

```
public class RecordFragment extends Fragment {

 private ArrayList<Record> scoreList;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, container, false);
    scoreList= new ArrayList<>();

    scoreList.add(new Record("Math", 10, "9/1/2017 13:45"));
    scoreList.add(new Record("Math", 8, "7/5/2017 10:50"));
    scoreList.add(new Record("Marh", 4, "7/7/2017 16:30"));

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(RecordFragment.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scoreList);

    ListView list1 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
 }

 private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Record>{
    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

    CustomAdapter(AppCompatActivity context){
        super(context, R.layout.record_fragment, scoreList);
        appCompatActivity = context;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = appCompatActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, null);

        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
        tv1 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        tv1.setText(scoreList.get(position).getTest());
        tv2.setText(scoreList.get(position).getScore());
        tv3.setText(scoreList.get(position).getDate());

        return item;
    }
 }

  public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
  }
}
```

This is the XML with the visual interface of each ListView item

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="" />
```

And this is the class I created to represent each ListView item

```
class Record{
  private String test, date;
  private int score;

  public Record(String test, int score, String date)
  {
    this.test= test;
    this.score= score;
    this.date = date;
  }

  public String getTest() {
    return test;
  }

  public int getScore(){
    return score;
  }

  public String getDate(){
    return date;
  }
}
```

If there is something else I have to show tell me, please.
Beforehand, thank you.

EDIT: I fixed some spelling mistakes. And this line in the Fragment doesn't compile:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(RecordFragment.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scoreList);
```

This message is displayed when I try to run it (I guest is the error log):

```
Error:(39, 40) error: constructor CustomAdapter in class RecordFragment.CustomAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
```

required: AppCompatActivity
found: FragmentActivity,int,ArrayList
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Please add error log too.

Comment: Are you sure your class `Record` compiles? The constructor seems strange.

Comment: Could you add fragment_record.xml file too? because it can be layout problem.

Comment: I don't think your code compiles with this code ; your adapter constructor is taking one parameter and you are passing Three HOW HOW !!! and your Adapter is taking AppCompatActivity , so if You RecordFragment.this.getActivity() and if the parent activity is not AppCompat it will crash anyway . just Use Context , you don't need to pass instance of your activity

Answer (score 1):

According to your question you are facing this problem

> after adding AppcompatActivity your app is not crashing but list is not showing anything

Your Adapter is asking for Context from your Activity which is AppCompat Type . So if when your host activity is not extending AppcompatActivity it will crash

So when you change it to AppcompatActivity it won't crash

Now lets solve the problem of showing a blank listView 
you didn't override the parent method `getCount()` . In the `getCount()` method return size items in your List.

Another thing `CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(RecordFragment.this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scoreList);` I don't think your code compiles with this line as your `AdaptadorHistorial(AppCompatActivity context){
        super(context, R.layout.record_fragment, scoreList);
        appCompatActivity = context;
     }` custom adapter is taking one parameter but you are passing two

your constructor should be like this

```
AdaptadorHistorial(Context context , List<Record> scoreList){
    super(context, R.layout.record_fragment, scoreList);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = scoreList;

 }



@override
public int getCount(){
 return items.size();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to write two parameter, it's the same one, I correct it already